# how to forward a message to a specific user in bale bot?

Tags: python, bale-messenger, balebot

how can i forward the message that user_a send the bot to user_b?
in other word how can i use user_peer to send message?

```
def new_message(bot, update):
     user_message_obj = update.get_effective_message()
     a = user_message_obj.text
     name_text = TextMessage(a)
     print("CheckPoint_1")
     peer = Peer(peer_type="User", peer_id="1621113162", access_hash="4481094213533037592")
     bot.send_message(name_text, peer, success_callback=success, failure_callback=failure)
     print("CheckPoint_2")
     message = TextMessage("پیام شما ثبت شد")
     user_peer = update.get_effective_user()
     bot.send_message(message, user_peer, success_callback=success, failure_callback=failure)
```

Comment: It's simple, you need just create a Peer object and call bot.send_message() to send a text message.

Comment: tnx_its worked.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to get effective message. after than you can use that effective message to send message to others.

```
def new_message(bot, update):
    user_message_obj = update.get_effective_message()
    print("CheckPoint_1")
    peer = Peer(peer_type="User", peer_id="1621113162", access_hash="4481094213533037592")
    bot.send_message(user_message_obj, peer, success_callback=success, failure_callback=failure)
    print("CheckPoint_2")
    message = TextMessage("پیام شما ثبت شد")
    user_peer = update.get_effective_user()
    bot.send_message(message, user_peer, success_callback=success, failure_callback=failure)
```